# Understanding Mathematic Symbols in Pseudocode

Tags: algorithms

I'm taking the [Algorithmic Toolbox](https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithmic-toolbox) course on Coursera and the instructor lectures are using many mathematic symbols in pseudocode that I'm not familiar with.

The lectures are presented with the assumption that students already know how to read these demarcations.

Can you please explain the meaning behind the symbols, especially:

```
# What is the {}? Empty object or hash?
R <- {}

# What are the brackets? Is the comma multiple assignment? Where did l come from?
[l,r] <- [xi, xi + 1] 

# Not sure exactly what's happening here.
R <- R U {[l,r]}
```

[image: Greedy Algorithm example]

Comment: Perhaps better suited for the computer science site. Someone here might know though.

Comment: It seems based on bad memories of CS courses past that $R$ is a set of ordered pairs of numbers, $\{\}$ is a notation for an empty set, $[l,r]\leftarrow [x_i, x_i+1]$ simply means "set the variable $[l,r]$ temporarily to be the ordered pair $[x_i, x_i+1]$," and $R\leftarrow R\cup \{[l,r]\}$ means "add the ordered pair $[l,r]$ to the set $R$."  If writing this pseudocode myself, I wouldn't introduce $[l,r]$ but would just write  $R\leftarrow R\cup \{[x_i,x_i+1]\}$.

Comment: You should ask on the Coursera forum for the course. They should define the symbols they use. $\{\}$ could be the empty set but you're right, if it's a programming language it could be an anonymous hash or some such.